# Some OBJs in Blender aren't loading properly for me

Tags: blender

Something really strange is happening, whenever I try to render or see my model in render view in Blender (newest version), I'm able to see through all the parts but still see the texture.. this has only started happening recently and I didn't upgrade versions or anything. The same thing happens to objects that I saved months before on new and even old project files. The (.obj) was exported from Roblox Studio. When in the Solid (default) or Wireframe viewport mode it looks normal, just not in any others.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

[Here's a picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLOcV.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

Fix: Instead of using Eevee, I switched to cycles which somehow fixed it.